# Jquery input value not update properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this html code. I need to update value="**0**"

```
<input id="loadmoreref" class="displynone" value="0" />
```

And html button is

```
<button id="loadmorebutton">Load more</button>
```

And i am using this jquery code

```
$(function(){
$('#loadmorebutton').click(function(){
var limstart = $("#loadmoreref").val();
$("#loadmoreref").val(limstart+3); //update value
alert(limstart );
});
```

when i click on button First time. alert say **0**. when i click once again it say **03** similarly **033**, **0333** etc.

Means it's adding 3 after last value.

But i need math addition (lastvalue+3) like that **0**, **3**, **6**, **9** etc instead **03**, **033**, **0333** etc.

Comment: You know values of attributes are strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding string to a number, convert string to number first using `parseInt()`. `$("#loadmoreref").val()` will result in a string.

```
$("#loadmoreref").val(parseInt(limstart,10)+3);
```

So for your understanding in JavaScript, adding string to a number is always a string.

```
"0" + 3 = "03"
"03" + 3 = "033"
"003" + 3 = "0333"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cast the val of #loadmoreref into number then use it and do the multiplication:

> Number(limstart) + 3

```
$("#loadmoreref").val(Number(limstart) + 3);
```

Note: Adding number to string will cast it to string then concatenate it with the string

```
 "hello" + 3 => "hello3"
 "6" + 3  => "63"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
$("#loadmoreref").val((limstart * 1) +3); //update value
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$(function(){
$('#loadmorebutton').click(function(){
var limstart = parseInt($("#loadmoreref").val());
$("#loadmoreref").val(limstart+3); //update value
alert(limstart );
});
```

.val() returns a string that needs to be converted to an Integer